# php and unbuntu 19.10

Tags: apache2, php

When I run php file in a browser instead of running file its open a box to save or open the file!!!
Whats the problem?
When I type this command:

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

*****************************
```

And the apache don't be active!!! Why?

Comment: What does executing "sudo apachectl configtest" output?

Comment: this is the output:sudo apachectl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the apache server:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2
```